# Developing a 1010 game in unity but pieces rearrange themselves sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid, game-physics

I have a bug in my game that I have spent day and night trying to solve but with no success, so please help if you can. Basicaly I have modified the grid(see picture for clarification) and everything seems to work except when I place the pieces at the corner or the edge pieces it suddenly change shape to fit the grid. I am not that good at describing things so I have taken a few screenshots to illustrate.

[When I start the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bD4M.png)

[When I try to set a piece in the grid but one piece is outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9IKO.png)

[Piece suddenly change shape, when it shouldn't fit and return to spawnpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a0tU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR8eM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEa3p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgBy.png)

Here is the code for that is attached to every tetris piece:

```
    public TetrimoPiece[] tetrimoPieces;
public Vector3 originalScale;
public Vector3 originalPos;
public Vector3 originalSpawnPos;

Vector3[] _minAndMaxPoints;
Vector3 _centroid;

public bool isBeingDragged;

public TetrimoSpawnPoint assignedSpawnPoint;
public int originalSortingOrder;

public Color color;

public int SortingOrder {

    get {
        return tetrimoPieces [0].SortingOrder;          
    }

    set {
        foreach (TetrimoPiece piece in tetrimoPieces) {
            piece.SortingOrder = value;
        }
    }

}

void Awake ()
{
    tetrimoPieces = GetChildTetrimoPieces ();
    originalSortingOrder = SortingOrder;

    originalScale = transform.localScale;
    originalPos = transform.localPosition;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0);

    if (tetrimoPieces.Count () > 0) {
        List<Transform> tetrimoPiecesTransforms = (from tetrimoPiece in tetrimoPieces
                                                   select tetrimoPiece.transform).ToList ();

        _minAndMaxPoints = GetMinAndMaxPoints (tetrimoPiecesTransforms);
        _centroid = FindCentroid (tetrimoPiecesTransforms);
    }

    SetTetrimoColor ();

}

void Start ()
{
}


public TetrimoPiece[] GetChildTetrimoPieces ()
{
    return GetComponentsInChildren<TetrimoPiece> ();
}

public void SetTetrimoColor(){
    foreach (TetrimoPiece piece in tetrimoPieces) {
        piece.SetColor(color);
    }
}

public void GenerateCollider ()
{

    List<Transform> tetrimoPiecesTransforms = new List<Transform> ();

    foreach (TetrimoPiece piece in tetrimoPieces) {
        tetrimoPiecesTransforms.Add (piece.transform);
    }

    Vector3[] minAndMaxPoints = GetMinAndMaxPoints (tetrimoPiecesTransforms);
    Vector3 minPoint = minAndMaxPoints [0];
    Vector3 maxPoint = minAndMaxPoints [1];

    BoxCollider2D boxColl = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();
    boxColl.size = new Vector2 ((maxPoint.x - minPoint.x) + tetrimoPieces [0].GetColliderSize ().x, (maxPoint.y - minPoint.y) + tetrimoPieces [0].GetColliderSize ().x);
}

public void MoveTetrimoPiecesToCenter ()
{
    List<Transform> tetrimoPiecesTransforms = new List<Transform> ();

    foreach (TetrimoPiece piece in tetrimoPieces) {
        tetrimoPiecesTransforms.Add (piece.transform);
    }

    Vector3 centroid = FindCentroid (tetrimoPiecesTransforms);

    foreach (Transform child in tetrimoPiecesTransforms) {
        child.position -= centroid;
    }
}


public Vector3[] GetMinAndMaxPoints (List<Transform> targets)
{

    Vector3 minPoint = targets [0].position;
    Vector3 maxPoint = targets [0].position;

    for (int i = 1; i < targets.Count; i++) {

        Vector3 pos = targets [i].position;
        if (pos.x < minPoint.x)
            minPoint.x = pos.x;
        if (pos.x > maxPoint.x)
            maxPoint.x = pos.x;
        if (pos.y < minPoint.y)
            minPoint.y = pos.y;
        if (pos.y > maxPoint.y)
            maxPoint.y = pos.y;
        if (pos.z < minPoint.z)
            minPoint.z = pos.z;
        if (pos.z > maxPoint.z)
            maxPoint.z = pos.z;
    }


    Vector3[] minAndMaxPoints = new Vector3[]{ minPoint, maxPoint };
    return minAndMaxPoints;
}


//CALCULATING THE MEDIAN POINT BETWEEN ALL TETRIMOS
private Vector3 FindCentroid (List< Transform > targets)
{
    Vector3 centroid;
    Vector3[] minAndMaxPoints = GetMinAndMaxPoints (targets);
    Vector3 minPoint = minAndMaxPoints [0];
    Vector3 maxPoint = minAndMaxPoints [1];

    centroid = minPoint + 0.5f * (maxPoint - minPoint);
    return centroid;
}

public void FollowInput ()
{
    Vector3 mouseScreenPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    mouseScreenPos.z = originalPos.z;

    transform.position = mouseScreenPos;
}

public bool CanBeReleasedOverGrid ()
{
    bool _canBeReleasedOverGrid = true;
    List<GridPiece> gridPiecesToFill = new List<GridPiece> ();

    foreach (TetrimoPiece piece in tetrimoPieces) {
        piece.SetNearestGridPiece ();
        gridPiecesToFill.Add (piece.lastNearestGridPiece);
    }
    foreach (GridPiece gridPiece in gridPiecesToFill) {
        if (gridPiece.isFilled || (TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial && !gridPiece.isTutorialFillable)) {
            _canBeReleasedOverGrid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (TetrimoPiecesShareSameNearestPiece ()) {
        _canBeReleasedOverGrid = false;
    }
    return _canBeReleasedOverGrid;
}

public bool TetrimoPiecesShareSameNearestPiece ()
{

    foreach (TetrimoPiece tetrimoPiece in tetrimoPieces) {

        foreach (TetrimoPiece brotherPiece in tetrimoPieces) {
            bool isBrother = tetrimoPiece != brotherPiece;

            if (isBrother) {                    
                if (tetrimoPiece.lastNearestGridPiece == brotherPiece.lastNearestGridPiece) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    return false;
}

public void FillNearestGridPieces ()
{
    foreach (TetrimoPiece tetrimoPiece in tetrimoPieces) {
        tetrimoPiece.lastNearestGridPiece.SetFilled (true);
        tetrimoPiece.lastNearestGridPiece.SetTetrimoThatFillsMe (this);
    }
}



public void PlaceOverGrid ()
{
    FillNearestGridPieces ();
    if (!TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial) {
        ScoreHandler.instance.increaseScore (tetrimoPieces.Count ());
    }
    DestroyImmediate (gameObject);
}



public void MoveToSpawnPosition ()
{
    transform.position = originalSpawnPos;
}

public bool CanFitInGrid ()
{
    GridPiece[] gridPieces = Grid.instance.gridPieces.ToArray ();
    bool canFitInGrid = false;

    Vector3 scaleBeforeCheck = transform.localScale;
    Vector3 positionBeforeCheck = transform.position;

    foreach (GridPiece gridPiece in gridPieces) {

        if (gridPiece != null)
        {
            transform.localScale = originalScale;
            transform.position = gridPiece.transform.position;
            transform.position += new Vector3(transform.position.x - tetrimoPieces[0].transform.position.x, transform.position.y - tetrimoPieces[0].transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            if (CanBeReleasedOverGrid())
            {
                canFitInGrid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    transform.position = positionBeforeCheck;
    transform.localScale = scaleBeforeCheck;

    return canFitInGrid;
}


public void ReturnToSpawnPoint (float timeToReachOriginalPos)
{

    if (OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine == null) {
        OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine = DOOnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine (timeToReachOriginalPos);
        StartCoroutine (OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine);
    }
}

public IEnumerator OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine;

public IEnumerator DOOnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine (float timeToReachOriginalPos, bool animated = true)
{

    float timeToReachValues = timeToReachOriginalPos;

    float t = 0;
    float timePassed = 0;

    Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 startScale = transform.localScale;
    Vector3 targetScale = originalScale * TetrimoSpawner.instance.scaleFactorOnSpawnPoint;

    if (!animated) {
        t = 1;
    }

    while (t <= 1) {

        if (this == null || isBeingDragged) {
            yield break;
        }


        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (startScale, targetScale, t);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos, originalSpawnPos, t);

        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToReachValues;
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        if (t >= 1) {

            transform.localScale = targetScale;
            transform.position = originalSpawnPos;

        }

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
    }


    OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine = null;
}



public void OnDrag ()
{

    if (OnDragRoutine == null) {
        isBeingDragged = true;
        OnDragRoutine = DOOnDragRoutine ();

        if (OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine != null) {
            StopCoroutine (OnReturnToSpawnPointRoutine);
        }

        StartCoroutine (OnDragRoutine);
    }
}

public void StopDrag ()
{
    if (OnDragRoutine != null) {
        isBeingDragged = false;
        StopCoroutine (OnDragRoutine);
        OnDragRoutine = null;
    }
}


public IEnumerator OnDragRoutine;

public IEnumerator DOOnDragRoutine ()
{
    float timeToReachValues = 0.1f;

    float t = 0;
    float timePassed = 0;

    Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 startScale = transform.localScale;

    while (t <= 1 && isBeingDragged) {

        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (startScale, originalScale, t);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos, GetFollowMousePos (), t);

        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToReachValues;
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        if (t >= 1) {
            transform.localScale = originalScale;
        }

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
    }

    while (isBeingDragged) {
        transform.position = GetFollowMousePos ();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
    }

}

public Vector3 GetFollowMousePos ()
{
    float distanceBetweenCenterAndTetrimoMinPoint = Mathf.Abs (_centroid.y - _minAndMaxPoints [0].y);

    Vector3 worldMousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    worldMousePos.z = transform.position.z;
    worldMousePos.y += distanceBetweenCenterAndTetrimoMinPoint + 1.15f;

    return worldMousePos;
}

public void OnDisable ()
{
    Vector3 targetScale = originalScale * TetrimoSpawner.instance.scaleFactorOnSpawnPoint;

    transform.position = originalSpawnPos;
    transform.localScale = targetScale;
}
```

and here is the code that is attached to every square pieces that makes up the prefab:

```
public BoxCollider2D coll;
public GridPiece lastNearestGridPiece;
private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

public int SortingOrder {
    get {
        return spriteRenderer.sortingOrder;
    }
    set {
        spriteRenderer.sortingOrder = value;
    }
}

public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer {
    get {
        if (_spriteRenderer == null) {
            _spriteRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();
        }
        return _spriteRenderer;
    }
}

void Awake ()
{
    coll = GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider2D> ();
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

}

public Vector2 GetColliderSize ()
{
    return coll.bounds.size;
}

public void SetNearestGridPiece ()
{

    GridPiece[] gridPieces = Grid.instance.gridPieces.ToArray ();

    GridPiece lastNearestGridPieceFound = gridPieces[0];

    float lastNearestDistanceFound = Vector3.Distance (gridPieces [0].transform.position, transform.position);

    foreach (GridPiece piece in gridPieces) {
        float distanceBetweenGridPieceAndThis = Vector3.Distance(piece.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (distanceBetweenGridPieceAndThis < lastNearestDistanceFound)
        {
            lastNearestGridPieceFound = piece;
            lastNearestDistanceFound = distanceBetweenGridPieceAndThis;
        }
    }

    lastNearestGridPiece = lastNearestGridPieceFound;
}

public void SetColor (Color color)
{
    spriteRenderer.color = color;
}
```

here is the code for generating grid:
    public static Grid instance;

```
public int rowsCount;
public int columnsCount;

public GridPiecesSet[] rows;
public GridPiecesSet[] columns;

public List<GridPiece> gridPieces;

public float distanceBetweenGroundPieces;
public GridPiece gridPiece;

GridPiecesContainer gridPiecesContainer;

void Awake ()
{
    instance = this;    
    gridPiecesContainer = GetComponentInChildren<GridPiecesContainer> ();
    GenerateGrid ();
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

}

//This generates the grid
public void GenerateGrid ()
{
    rows = Enumerable.Range (0, columnsCount).Select (i => new GridPiecesSet (columnsCount, GridPiecesSet.Type.row)).ToArray ();
    columns = Enumerable.Range (0, rowsCount).Select (i => new GridPiecesSet (rowsCount, GridPiecesSet.Type.column)).ToArray ();

    gridPieces = new List<GridPiece> ();

    for (int rowsIndex = 0; rowsIndex < rowsCount; rowsIndex++) {
        GenerateRow (rowsIndex);
    }

    gridPiecesContainer.MoveToCenter ();

}

void GenerateRow (int rowsIndex)
{
    GridPiece lastSpawnedRowPiece = null;

    for (int columnsIndex = 0; columnsIndex < columnsCount; columnsIndex++) {
        if (rowsIndex == 0 && columnsIndex == 4 || columnsIndex == 5)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 3 && columnsIndex <= 6) && rowsIndex == 1)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 2 && columnsIndex <= 7) && rowsIndex == 2)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 1 && columnsIndex <= 8) && rowsIndex == 3)
        {

            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if (rowsIndex == 4)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if (rowsIndex == 5)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 1 && columnsIndex <= 8) && rowsIndex == 6)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 2 && columnsIndex <= 7) && rowsIndex == 7)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 3 && columnsIndex <= 6) && rowsIndex == 8)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
        else if ((columnsIndex >= 4 && columnsIndex <= 5) && rowsIndex == 9)
        {
            GridPiece newGridPiece = Instantiate(gridPiece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            newGridPiece.transform.SetParent(gridPiecesContainer.transform);

            Vector3 newPos = newGridPiece.transform.position;

            // GENERATING FROM TOP LEFT
            newPos.x = (newGridPiece.GetWidth() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * columnsIndex;
            newPos.y = (newGridPiece.GetHeight() / 2 + distanceBetweenGroundPieces) * (-rowsIndex);

            newGridPiece.transform.position = newPos;
            newGridPiece.name = " piece_row_" + rowsIndex + " piece_col_" + columnsIndex;

            rows[rowsIndex].gridPieces[columnsIndex] = newGridPiece;
            columns[columnsIndex].gridPieces[rowsIndex] = newGridPiece;

            gridPieces.Add(newGridPiece);


            lastSpawnedRowPiece = newGridPiece.GetComponent<GridPiece>();
        }
    }
}

public bool IsGameOver ()
{

    bool gameOver = true;

    foreach (Tetrimo tetrimo in TetrimoSpawner.instance.spawnedTetrimos) {

        if (tetrimo != null) {
            if (tetrimo.CanFitInGrid ()) {
                gameOver = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }           

    return gameOver;
}

public void CleanCompletedRowsAndColumns ()
{

    List<GridPiecesSet> rowsAndColumnsToClean = new List<GridPiecesSet> ();

    foreach (GridPiecesSet row in rows) {
        if (row.AllPiecesFilled () && row.colorMatch()) {
            rowsAndColumnsToClean.Add (row);
        }
    }

    foreach (GridPiecesSet column in columns) {
        if (column.AllPiecesFilled () && column.colorMatch()) {
            rowsAndColumnsToClean.Add (column);
        }
    }

    if (rowsAndColumnsToClean.Count > 0) {
        ClearAllCompletedRowsAndColumns (rowsAndColumnsToClean);
    }

}

public void ClearAllCompletedRowsAndColumns (List<GridPiecesSet> rowsAndColumnsToClean)
{

    SoundsManager.instance.PlayLineCompleted ();

    foreach (GridPiecesSet pieceSet in rowsAndColumnsToClean) {
        pieceSet.Clean ();
        StartCoroutine (DOCleanAnimation (pieceSet));
    }

}

public void ClearGrid ()
{
    foreach (GridPiece gridPiece in gridPieces) {
        gridPiece.SetFilled (false);
    }
}

public GridPieceConfiguration[] GetCurrentGridConfiguration ()
{

    GridPieceConfiguration[] gridConfig = new GridPieceConfiguration[gridPieces.Count ()];

    int count = 0;
    foreach (GridPiece gridPiece in gridPieces) {
        gridConfig [count] = new GridPieceConfiguration ();
        gridConfig [count].ActivationState = gridPiece.isFilled;
        gridConfig [count].TetrimoThatFillsName = gridPiece.tetrimoPieceThatFillsMeName;
        count++;
    }

    return gridConfig;
}

public void TurnOffAllTutorialFillablePieces ()
{
    foreach (GridPiece piece in gridPieces) {
        piece.SetIlluminated (false);
        piece.SetTutorialFillable (false);
    }
}

public void SetGridByConfiguration (GridPieceConfiguration[] configs)
{

    int count = 0;
    foreach (GridPieceConfiguration config in configs) {

        GridPiece iteratedPiece = gridPieces [count];

        if (config.ActivationState == true) {
            iteratedPiece.SetFilled (true);

            Tetrimo tetrimoThatFillsGridPiece = Resources.Load<Tetrimo> ("Tetrimos/" + config.TetrimoThatFillsName);
            if (tetrimoThatFillsGridPiece == null) {
                throw new UnassignedReferenceException ();
            }
            iteratedPiece.SetTetrimoThatFillsMe (tetrimoThatFillsGridPiece);


        } else {
            iteratedPiece.SetFilled (false);
        }

        iteratedPiece.SetIlluminated (false);
        iteratedPiece.SetTutorialFillable (true);

        count++;
    }
}


public IEnumerator DOCleanAnimation (GridPiecesSet piecesSet)
{

    List<GridPiece> gridPiecesToAnimate = new List<GridPiece> ();

    foreach (GridPiece piece in piecesSet.gridPieces) {
        if (piece != null)
        {
            GridPiece clonePiece = GameObject.Instantiate(piece.gameObject).GetComponent<GridPiece>();
            clonePiece.transform.position = piece.transform.position;
            clonePiece.graphicWhenFilled.sortingOrder += 10;
            clonePiece.SetFilled(true);
            gridPiecesToAnimate.Add(clonePiece);
        }
    }

    foreach (GridPiece piece in gridPiecesToAnimate) {
        if (piece != null)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DisappearAnim(piece, piecesSet));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);
        }
    }

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
}


IEnumerator DisappearAnim (GridPiece piece, GridPiecesSet piecesSet)
{

    float t = 0;
    float animTime = 0.15f;

    Vector3 startScale = piece.transform.localScale;
    Vector3 targetScale = Vector3.zero;

    while (t <= 1) {

        piece.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp (startScale, targetScale, t);

        t += Time.deltaTime / animTime;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

        if (t >= 1) {
            piece.transform.localScale = targetScale;
        }
    }

    piece.DestroySelf ();
}
```

and finally the inputhandler that handles input from mouse or touch

```
    bool isDragging = false;
Tetrimo tetrimoToMove = null;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
}


void Update ()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        OnMouseButtonDown ();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        OnMouseButtonUp ();
    }

    if (isDragging) {
        OnDrag ();
    }


}

public void OnDrag ()
{
    tetrimoToMove.OnDrag ();
}

public void OnMouseButtonUp ()
{
    if (isDragging) {

        if (tetrimoToMove.CanBeReleasedOverGrid ()) {                       
            Debug.Log("Mouse Up");
            if (TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial) {
                StartCoroutine (TutorialManager.instance.OnTetrimoReleasedOverGrid ());
            }

            SoundsManager.instance.PlayTetrimoPlacement ();
            tetrimoToMove.PlaceOverGrid ();
            Grid.instance.CleanCompletedRowsAndColumns ();

            if (Grid.instance.IsGameOver () && !TetrimoSpawner.instance.HasToSpawnNewTetrimos () && !TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial) {
                StartCoroutine(ObliusGameManager.instance.GameOver ());
                Debug.Log ("GAME OVER");
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("GAME CAN CONTINUE");
            }

            if (!TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial) {
                GameStateSerializer.SaveCurrentState (Grid.instance, TetrimoSpawner.instance, ScoreHandler.instance);
            }

            if (!TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial && TetrimoSpawner.instance.HasToSpawnNewTetrimos()) {                   
                StartCoroutine (TetrimoSpawner.instance.TetrimoSpawnRoutine (true));    
            }

        } else {                        
            tetrimoToMove.StopDrag ();
            tetrimoToMove.ReturnToSpawnPoint (0.1f);
        }
    }

    isDragging = false;
}

public void OnMouseButtonDown ()
{
    if (!isDragging && ObliusGameManager.instance.gameState != ObliusGameManager.GameState.gameover) {
        tetrimoToMove = GetClickedTetrimo ();

        if (tetrimoToMove != null) {

            if (TutorialManager.instance.isShowingTutorial) {

                if (tetrimoToMove.assignedSpawnPoint != TutorialManager.instance.currentShownTutorialStep.clickableSpawnPoint) {
                    isDragging = false;
                    return;
                }

                TutorialManager.instance.tutorialhand.StopMoveAndHide ();
            }
            isDragging = true;

        } else {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    }
}


public Tetrimo GetClickedTetrimo ()
{

    Tetrimo clickedTetrimo = null;

    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = 10;

    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (screenPos, Vector2.zero);
    if (hit) {

        Tetrimo hitTetrimo = hit.transform.GetComponentInParent<Tetrimo> ();
        TetrimoSpawnPoint hitSpawnPoint = hit.transform.GetComponent<TetrimoSpawnPoint> ();

        if (hitTetrimo != null) {
            clickedTetrimo = hitTetrimo;
        } else if (hitSpawnPoint != null) {
            clickedTetrimo = hitSpawnPoint.assignedTetrimo;
            Debug.Log ("Spawn point hit");
        }
    } 

    return clickedTetrimo;
}
```

Comment: If you need more information, just ask

Comment: When is CanFitInGrid() called? Should it be  
``` if (isDragging) {

        if (tetrimoToMove.CanFitInGrid ()) { 
```
it seems you already call CanBeReleasedOverGrid in CanFitInGrid. But there is no mention of CanFitInGrid for what you have included.
You're also calling several functions that you haven't included. Which makes it hard to come to a conclusion what could be your issue.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, hopes this makes things more clear, and canfitingrid is called by the grid script to determine if it should transition to game over screen or not

Comment: how are the terminos build up? Is each square segment a prefab? So a the T terminos is 3 squares? If they are individual prefabs grouped together. Looking at the screenshots it looks like your FillNearestGridPieces is kicking in when a square is outside available grid pieces. I haven't digested all your update code sorry.

Comment: It's ok, just take your time, the terminos are basically an empty gameobject with squares adding up to build a shape, the T terminos if you refer to the red on in the pictures is built up by 4 squares. I have prefabs of all the shapes, and inside them is just the square pieces grouped together. Your right in that the fillnearestgridpiece has something to do with it, but I can't figure out why, basically it returns false at first and then true when the bug is happening.

Comment: Why does this have a `unity3d` tag, when it is obviously 2D? Are you using the 3D engine and a top-down camera?

Comment: Hi, sorry it's made with unity2d, I don't know why I put unity3d, sorry, I will fix it